# Revert git checkout

Tags: git, github

I have changed some files, then did the following to push to github:

- I checked on which branch I am: `git branch` and found it's branch called `test`.
- I wanted to change the branch to master, so instead of doing `git checkout master`, I did `git checkout`.
- Then, I did `git add -A`.
- `git push origin master`.

After I opened the project, I found that I discarded all the changes and reverted to last `test` changes.

My question is:  I want to revert to my last local changes. Is it possible?

Comment: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/merge_requests/revert_changes.html

Comment: @TomaszAdamczyk i saw the link and its about merge request. He did checkout and it discarded all his local changes and link is not helpful in this context

Comment: Also: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/merge_requests/revert_changes.html#reverting-a-commit

Comment: Question is, was those changes committed?

Comment: @TomaszAdamczyk Yes I committed the changes

Comment: @MEnnabah tried `git reset --hard commit_sha` ?

Comment: No, what should I expect if I run it?

Comment: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-reset If You have previous commit hash, You can go back with git reset. You can use `git log` to get history.

Comment: @TomaszAdamczyk Thanks that helped me.

Answer (score 0):

did you add those changes on stash or index before you run the `git checkout` ? if not, i think there is no way to get them back.

Answer (score 0):

1. If you have stashed your changes:

use "git stash apply "

2. If you have committed you changes:

use "git checkout " or use git-cherrypick.

3. If you have neither stashed nor committed then, If you are using an IDE.  right-click on the project and got to localHistory: You will see lot of previous histories. Replace with the one you want.